# Python imports, packages, and runnable scripts

Tags: python, python-import

I've read the following post:

[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

It explains the difference between running a file as a top-level script and importing it as a module in remarkable clarity and detail.

I can't figure out, however, how to write the imports of a runnable script (`if __name__ == '__main__'` et cetera) in a way which I'd also be able to import it from my tests, all the while keeping my runnable scripts stand-alone (i.e. not requiring package installation).

Say I have the following project hierarchy:

```
/reporoot
    /mypkg
        /mysubpkg
            __init__.py
            subpkgmodule.py
        __init__.py
        main1.py
        main2.py
    /tests
        test_main1.py
        test_main2.py
```

`test_main1` needs to import `main1` in some manner, and `main1` needs to import `subpkgmodule` in some manner.
If, for instance, `main1` imports `subpkgmodule` like so:

```
import mysubpkg.subpkgmodule
```

This will work fine when running the script as the top-level script because the top level script has its directory added to `sys.path`. This import will break, however, when the module is imported rather than run (because its directory will not be added to `sys.path`).

If `main1` were to import `subpkgmodule` like so:

```
import mypkg.mysubpkg.subpkgmodule
```

This will only work when the package is an installed package (including `python setup.py develop`) and not running as a standalone script (i.e. chuck it on some filesystem and run `python main1.py`).

I saw that the standard library's `http.server` module has an `import http.client` and therefore cannot be run as a standalone script as I mentioned.

What would a clean solution for the imports of my runnable scripts be?

Answer (score 1):

Typical way would be to extend [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) in runnable script with location of your package.

> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules.
>   Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an
>   installation-dependent default.
>
> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list,
>   path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to
>   invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not
>   available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the
>   script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string,
>   which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first.
>   Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries
>   inserted as a result of PYTHONPATH.
>
> A program is free to modify this list for its own purposes.

Sample `test_main1.py`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))

import mypkg.mysubpkg.subpkgmodule   # should import fine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass  # runnable code here
```

Comment: I had thought about doing this via some `testenv` module that all the tests would import first, but it seemed inelegant

Answer (score 0):

Libraries such as the built-in `unittest` have built-in test discovery. By default, it expects tests to be in files named with the pattern `test*.py`, where the asterisk (*) may be whatever you'd like. You'd then use `discover` and run the package using:

```
python -m unittest discover
```

This assumes that

1. you are using `unittest`,
2. your tests subclass `unittest.TestCase`, and
3. you use the default class `unittest.TestLoader`.